# Pandas: single series with alternate y-Axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using Pandas and (preferably) Matplotlib, is it possible to plot a single series with two y-axes (one on the left, one on the right)? All the examples I've found are for two series, each relating independantly to its own y-axis.

An example would be a series of temperature readings over time, with the left y-axis calibrated in °C and the right in °F.

Quite happy to introduce a second series to hold the values for the alternate scale if that helps, as long as the final result is a single visible series with two y-axes properly correlated (e.g. so that 0°C on the left correlates to 32°F on the right).

Comment: See `f, ax = plt.subplots(); ax1 = ax.twinx()`

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html ... there's literally a Fahrenheit and Celsius example.

Comment: Looks promising, @BigBen! I'll try to follow that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full credit: the solution @BigBen linked to in the above comment answers the question perfectly. Here's the link again: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/fahrenheit_celsius_scales.html